# Eclipse / CCS Bug - Uses All Memory On Clean Project

Tags: eclipse, code-composer

I'm having a problem with CCS6, which is based on Eclipse.  I'm trying to build a demo project that comes with a TI MSP430 demo board.  When I build the project CCS/Eclipse proceeds to clean the project, during which all the memory on my system is slowly consumed.  After memory usage reaches 100% Windows declares that CCS/Eclipse is having problems and asks to close it down.

I am running Windows 8.1.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled CCS several times, versions 5.5 and 6.0.  I get the same behavior every time.  I also updated the version of Java on my system.  I have reached out to TI support engineers and they are baffled and useless. I have also tried with a second computer also running Windows 8.1, same behavior.

The problem is obviously rooted with gmake somehow.  Perhaps there is something wrong with the project files causing this behavior?  I haven't experimented with other projects yet.

Thanks!

P.S. I wanted to post screen shots but StackOverflow isn't letting me.  The window I see in CCS/Eclipse is titled "Cleaning selected projects" and then reads "Invoking Command: c:\ti\ccsv6\utils\bin\gmake -k clean"  And it just stays on this forever.  Using Task Manager I can then see my memory slowly filling up.  After about 5 minutes or so it reaches 100% use and Windows asks to shut down CCS.

Comment: `and they are baffled and useless` -  :p that sounded funny

Comment: Eclipse has a lot of junk attached, I think I recall that turning spelling off gives a ton of memory. Look up "reduce eclipse memory" et al

Comment: Spelling doesn't take that much memory. How much physical memory does the system have, and how much is Eclipse allowed to use?

Comment: 16GB, only 2.2GB in use when I open CCS.  Eclipse can and does use all the rest when trying to clean project.